# Retrofit Post with arraylist as field

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit

I'm trying to do a POST method using Retrofit library. The issue is located on the fourth field of the POST code:

```
@POST("/user/agenda/contacts")
    void createContact(
            @Field("contact[token]") String token,
            @Field("contact[name]") String name,
            @Field("contact[default_phone_number_token]") String defaultPhone,
            @Field("contact[sub_contacts]")List<SubContact> subContacts,
            Callback<Contact> contact) throws RetrofitError;
```

As you can see, this field contains an arrayList containing another object model. The API does not process the request because this parameter is not ewllformed when creating the json.

Can anyone tell me how to map correctly the object (SubContact)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a wild shot, have you tried `SubContract[]` ?

Answer (score 0):

What version of `retrofit` are you using? There is support for using list in `@Field`s since 1.4.0